# If I swear "I will not do..." with my hand on my head, is it considered an oath?

Tags: oaths

Keeping my hand on my head, if I say "I will not do..." is it considered an oath?  How could I do it again, if necessary?

Comment: You swear by intent I suppose. Doesn't matter where your hand was while you're swearing.

Answer (score 1):

There are some points regarding the issue of swearing as you inquired

> keeping hand on head,if i says ",I will not do",is it considered as
>   swear?Please answer .If the answer is positive(yes),what will be the
>   solution to do it again?

- One of those points which are related to the swear, is concerning
  how to say it. In other word, your swearing would be right
  in case you say it by your tongue. Therefore as what I founded as a
  related and actually answer your question, the answer would be that
  it seems unrelated about keeping hand on head…
- As another condition of the swearing: is related to being at the age
  of puberty and to be wise (Aqel)
- What you are swearing, ought not to be haram or Makruh…

  ---

**Conclusion**:

Keeping hand on the head doesn’t seem to be related as a relevant item to the swear (or at least as a main item). In the meanwhile I recommend you to read the reference below in order to obtain more complete answer.

---

Reference:

- [www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/ar/archive/question/fa3721)

Answer (score 0):

It is not permissible to swear on anything other than the name of Allah otherwise it is seen as shirk. Putting your hand on someone's head to say you swear on their life is haraam. However if you did not say you swear on their life, what matters is your intention.

Comment: Any references?

Answer (score 0):

It is only allowed to swear by God, swearing by other things is not accepted and does not count. Only God can swear with any thing he creates.

Comment: "It is only allowed to swear by God" any references?